# ruby debugger step into a block directly?

Tags: ruby, debugging

In the following Ruby code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

require 'debugger'

def hello
  puts "hello"
  if block_given?
    yield
  end 
end 

def main
  debugger
  puts "test begin..."
  hello do   # <=  if you are here
    puts "here!" #<= how to get here without setting bp here or step into hello?
  end 
end 

main
```

It's very common during debugging, I don't care about the implementation of the function that yields to the block, I just want to step into the block directly, without manually setting a break-point there.

Does any support for this kind of "step into block" exist in ruby-debug19 or debugger?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried using the "`c`" command, for "[continue](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html#Continue)"? It optionally takes a line number, so, based on your code sample try:

```
c 16
```

Comment: This is as close to a "step into current block" as I had hoped for, thanks!

Comment: How does that help?  Doesn't `c` just cause it to run to the end?

Comment: `c 16` would run until it hit line 16. Per the documentation: `The optional argument line-specification allows you to specify a line number to set a one-time breakpoint which is deleted when that breakpoint is reached.`